# Problem with table caption

Tags: tables

I want to create a table using TeXworks. I could do it using `tabular` environment, but when I put caption above the table I get an error. The code is as follows. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

```
 \begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{l l l l l l}
        {\caption{Table 1: The coeffcient of determination ($R^2$) for validation set (dataset C) obtained by applying different preprocessing techniques.}}

        {\label{Table 1}}
        \hline

 Trans & Dry & Moisture-1 & Moisture-2 & Moisture-3 & Moisture-4\\

        \hline

Raw & 0.79 & -184.32 & -100.21 &    -53.74 & -13.02\\

MSC & 0.76 & -5.82 & -4.58 & -3.02 & -1.88\\

SNV & 0.75 & -423.19 & -188.19 & -69.23 & -7.95\\

FD & 0.71 & -6.12 & -4.13 & -3.26 & -2.19\\

        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end(center)
```

Comment: Oh my, there are some issues here ;-)  `\caption` needs a `table` environment or use `\captionof{table}{...} and `\begin{center}` requires `\end{center}`, not `\end(center)` (however, the `center` - environment shouldn't be inside a floating environment like `table` then.

Comment: this might be as simple as moving the `\caption` and its `\label` *outside* the `tabular` environment.  (but if it's not within a `table` -- floating -- environment, you need `\captionof`, still *outside* the `tabular`.)

Answer (score 6):

It is good, that the code in the question does not contain vertical lines. That makes the table more professional looking.

I do not want to comment on the remaining issues, you might want to get a good LaTeX book. The table can be set as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% nicer horizontal lines
\usepackage{caption}% fix vertical spacing of table captions
\usepackage{siunitx}% align numbers at the decimal point

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{The coeffcient of determination ($R^2$) for
    validation set (dataset~C) obtained by applying different preprocessing
    techniques.}
  \label{Table 1}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=-3.2]
    S[table-format=-3.2]
    S[table-format=-2.2]
    S[table-format=-2.2]
  }
    \toprule
    Trans & {Dry}
    & {Moisture-1} & {Moisture-2} & {Moisture-3} & {Moisture-4}\\
    \midrule
    Raw & 0.79 & -184.32 & -100.21 &    -53.74 & -13.02\\
    MSC & 0.76 & -5.82 & -4.58 & -3.02 & -1.88\\
    SNV & 0.75 & -423.19 & -188.19 & -69.23 & -7.95\\
    FD & 0.71 & -6.12 & -4.13 & -3.26 & -2.19\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

the key problem here is that the `\caption` must be outside the `tabular` environment.

there are also some other problems:

- `\end(center)` should have braces, not parentheses: `\end{center}`
- when the `\caption` is outside the `tabular`, it is numbered automatically, so you end up with "Table 1: Table 1:"; remove that string from the caption text
- it's possibly better to enclose this in a "floating" environment, i.e. `\begin{table} ... \end{table}`; otherwise you will need `\captionof{...}` instead of just `\caption` (and also `\usepackage{captionof}`)
- if you do use the `table` environment, use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` for better vertical spacing
- the negative values in the table have hyphens instead of minus signs; for real minus signs, you need to put these values into math mode, e.g. `$184.32`, and for consistency, all numeric values in the table should be treated the same
- numeric values in a table, especially when all have the same number of decimal places, really look better flush right than flush left

other improvements are possible, but that's enough for now.

here's the result:

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

 \caption{The coeffcient of determination ($R^2$) for validation set (dataset C) obtained by applying different preprocessing techniques.}
        \label{Table 1}

    \begin{tabular}{l r r r r r}
        \hline

 Trans & Dry & Moisture-1 & Moisture-2 & Moisture-3 & Moisture-4\\

        \hline

Raw & $0.79$ & $-184.32$ & $-100.21$ & $   -53.74$ & $-13.02$\\

MSC & $0.76$ & $-5.82$ & $-4.58$ & $-3.02$ & $-1.88$\\

SNV & $0.75$ & $-423.19$ & $-188.19$ & $-69.23$ & $-7.95$\\

FD & $0.71$ & $-6.12$ & $-4.13$ & $-3.26$ & $-2.19$\\

        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd remove the braces around `\caption`

Comment: @egreg -- right you are.  `\label` too.  (now why did i put them there in the first place???  shakes head, confused.)

Comment: They were in the original code. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you would mention the error. However, one thing which is wrong is that with \end{center} you used normal braces and not curly braces. As such your centre environment is not properly ended. Furthermore, let me propose the following solution:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{The coeffcient of determination ($R^2$) for validation set (dataset C) obtained by applying different preprocessing techniques.}\label{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l l}

    \hline

Trans & Dry & Moisture-1 & Moisture-2 & Moisture-3 & Moisture-4\\

    \hline

Raw & 0.79 & -184.32 & -100.21 &    -53.74 & -13.02\\

MSC & 0.76 & -5.82 & -4.58 & -3.02 & -1.88\\

SNV & 0.75 & -423.19 & -188.19 & -69.23 & -7.95\\

FD & 0.71 & -6.12 & -4.13 & -3.26 & -2.19\\

    \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This way you don't have to explicitly state Table 1, centering is done properly, and the caption will also not give you an error.

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to put \begin(Table) to write the caption; I mean that cannot I just write the caption into tabular environment itself.

Comment: It's most certainly not required. For example, you could use \captionof{table}{My caption text}. For that macro to work you need to import the caption package (\usepackage{caption} in your preamble). The macro \captionof needs to be placed above your tabular. However the table environment is more clear and conventional. Furthermore, the table is a float object, while the tabular on its own is not. As such you can't really position(/float) the tabular on its own (as you would normally with other tables, figures and float objects).

Comment: @user147798 `\begin(Table)` won't work. You're probably mistaking it for `\begin{table}`

Answer (score 0):

I propose three solutions to improve the table:

A first solution does not use the `table` environment, and uses the \ captionof` command. The caption width is largert than the table width.

A second solution uses the `threeparttable` environment. Thus the caption width is excatly the table width. You can use the `\caption` command.

A third solution is based on the `\ltablex` package, which combines the possibilities of `tabularx` and `longtable`. You  have a control on the table width, and the caption is included in the first head of the table, as in a lontable environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% nicer horizontal lines
\usepackage{caption}% fix vertical spacing of table captions
\usepackage{siunitx}% align numbers at the decimal point
\usepackage{threeparttable, ltablex}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{The coefficient of determination ($R^2$) for
  validation set (dataset~C) obtained by applying different preprocessing
  techniques.}\vskip\abovecaptionskip
\label{Table 1a}
\begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=-3.2]
    S[table-format=-3.2]
    S[table-format=-2.2]
    S[table-format=-2.2]
    }
    \toprule
    Trans & {Dry}
    & {Moisture-1} & {Moisture-2} & {Moisture-3} & {Moisture-4}\\
    \midrule
    Raw & 0.79 & -184.32 & -100.21 & -53.74 & -13.02 \\
    MSC & 0.76 & -5.82 & -4.58 & -3.02 & -1.88 \\
    SNV & 0.75 & -423.19 & -188.19 & -69.23 & -7.95 \\
    FD & 0.71 & -6.12 & -4.13 & -3.26 & -2.19 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \vskip1cm

  \begin{threeparttable}

    \caption{The coefficient of determination ($R^2$) for
      validation set (dataset~C) obtained by applying different preprocessing
      techniques.}\vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \label{Table 1b}
    \begin{tabular}{
        l
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=-3.2]
        S[table-format=-3.2]
        S[table-format=-2.2]
        S[table-format=-2.2]
        }
        \toprule
        Trans & {Dry}
        & {Moisture-1} & {Moisture-2} & {Moisture-3} & {Moisture-4}\\
        \midrule
        Raw & 0.79 & -184.32 & -100.21 & -53.74 & -13.02 \\
        MSC & 0.76 & -5.82 & -4.58 & -3.02 & -1.88 \\
        SNV & 0.75 & -423.19 & -188.19 & -69.23 & -7.95 \\
        FD & 0.71 & -6.12 & -4.13 & -3.26 & -2.19 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \vskip1cm

    \keepXColumns
    \begin{tabularx}{0.85\linewidth}{
        X
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=-3.2]
        S[table-format=-3.2]
        S[table-format=-2.2]
        S[table-format=-2.2]
        }
        \captionsetup{width=0.85\linewidth}
        \caption{The coefficient of determination ($R^2$) for
        validation set (dataset~C) obtained by applying different preprocessing
        techniques.}\label{Table 1c}
        \endhead
        \addlinespace[\abovecaptionskip]
        \toprule
        Trans & {Dry}
        & {Moisture-1} & {Moisture-2} & {Moisture-3} & {Moisture-4}\\
        \midrule
        Raw & 0.79 & -184.32 & -100.21 & -53.74 & -13.02 \\
        MSC & 0.76 & -5.82 & -4.58 & -3.02 & -1.88 \\
        SNV & 0.75 & -423.19 & -188.19 & -69.23 & -7.95 \\
        FD & 0.71 & -6.12 & -4.13 & -3.26 & -2.19 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]